# Laravel 4 Populate Form fields with a Model but edit the field first

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with PHP and Laravel 4.  Using the Form method to populate an edit form with a Model like below...

```
Form::model($timecard, array('route' => array("admin/timecard/edit", $id)))
```

My problem is, some of the text fields get populated with DateTime values from the Database and I need to be able to run some code on these certain fields before it populates the Form field.

Any ideas how to do that or if it's possible to do that while still using the Model to auto-fill the Form fields?

For example this form field below gets filed with a GET value, otherwise it gets field with the Data from the Database for column `clock_in_datetime` however I would like to run a PHP function on this field before it fills the form so that I can apply TimeZone or other formatting to it...

```
{{ Form::text("clock_in_datetime", Input::get("clock_in_datetime"), array(
    "placeholder" => "2013-09-04 14:22:35",
    'class' => 'form-control'
)) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do the following:

```
{{ Form::text("clock_in_datetime", yourFormattingFunction(Form::getValueAttribute("clock_in_datetime")), array(
    "placeholder" => "2013-09-04 14:22:35",
    'class' => 'form-control'
)) }}
```

`Form::getValueAttribute()` is Laravel's way of deciding which value to use (previous Input, Session or Model). So you can apply your formatting function to the output of this function.

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#751-773